# How can I add additional items to a store array and still be able to set the array to empty when resetting?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I've set up a Store.js with a players array. I want to add players to the array as I select them but still be able to set the array to empty if I clear the array.

Here is some code from my Store.js

```
const initialState = {
    playerCollection: [],
}


const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'UPDATE_PLAYER_COLLECTION':
          return { ...state, playerCollection: action.value };

        default:
          return state;
    }
}
```

Here is some code from my Players.js

```
for(let i=0; i<players.length; i++){
    let player = players[i];
    
    if(player.position === state.posAbbr && player.status === 'ACT'){
        let newPlayer = createNewPlayer(roster, player);

        dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_PLAYER_COLLECTION', value: [...state.playerCollection, newPlayer] });
        return;
    }
}
```

My dispatch line is only adding a single player to the playerCollection array.
I also want to, like I said above, be able to set the array to [] if I clear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a clear playerCollection action, and set array to empty in reducer for that action:

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
 switch (action.type) {
    case 'UPDATE_PLAYER_COLLECTION':
      return { ...state, playerCollection: action.value };
    case 'CLEAR_PLAYERS':
       return {...state,playerCollection: []};
    case "ADD_PLAYER" :
        return {...state,playerCollection : [...state.playerCollection,action.value]}
    default:
      return state;
 }
}
```

Comment: Good point for clearing the array. How do I add players to the collection? It's currently setting the array to 1 player when I try to add.

Comment: I have added ADD_PLAYER action which uses destructring to add new player to existing array.